# Selecting both labeled and not labeled values from Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure-app-configuration

In my Azure App Configuration I have 2 keys, one of them has label.

```
Alpha:A = '1' [no-label]
Alpha:B = '2' [no-label]
Alpha:B = '3' ['Api' label]
```

I would like to select all Alpha keys but if they have label, load 'Api'.
Currently I do this: First select all then select 'Api' label to overwrite the previous ones.

```
.Select("Alpha:*",LabelFilter.Null)
.Select("Alpha:*","Api")
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the solution provided in the Azure App Configuration documentation best practices section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-best-practices#key-value-compositions

Comment: Thanks J.,
My code is based on that but I was wondering if we can use "label=%00,1.0.0" pattern somehow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-key-value